# Error in profile 2 while updating programatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, user-profile

EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type profile2. in entity_extract_ids()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error usually comes if profile2 does not exist for user. Please make sure if user you are updating has valid profile entity. You can check profile2 by using the function profile2_load_by_user($account, $type_name = NULL).

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, Really Appreciate it